# How many combinations of unique pairs can be formed from $n$ digits if no element in one pair can be equal to the elements of other pairs?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many combinations of unique pairs can be formed from $n$ digits if no element in one pair can be equal to the elements of other pairs?

We can consider a die which has $6$ digits. In how many ways can these be paired paired? Configuring the opposite of a digit $d$ as $O(d)$, one way would be $O(1)=2, O(3)=4, O(5)=6,$ so that the pairs are $\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{5,6\}.$ Another way may be $O(1)=3, O(2)=4, O(5)=6,$ so that the pairs are $\{1,3\},\{2,4\},\{5,6\}.$ In total, I found that there are $15$ possible configurations.

How can I extend this to larger numbers?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: If the "pairs" are unordered, it is better to use set notation for doubletons, i.e. $\{1,2\}$ rather than $(1,2)$.

Comment: Are you interested in counting pairs when $n$ is odd?

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume we have $2n$ numbers, which we want to divide into $n$ pairs. To achieve this, we can order all $2n$ numbers from left to right, which can be done in $(2n)!$ ways. We can then pair the first and the second number, the third and the fourth number, etc.

Using such approach, there are multiple occurrences for every pair: in the case of a die, for instance, $\{1, 6\} = \{6, 1\}$. For each pair, we must thus divide by $2$. Furthermore, the order of the pairs does not matter either: in the case of a die, the order $\{1, 2\}, \{3, 4\}, \{5, 6\}$ results in the same pair-wise combination as $\{3, 4\}, \{1, 2\}, \{5, 6\}$. We must thus divide by $n!$, the number of ways to order the pairs.

All in all, the number of ways to pair the $2n$ numbers equals:

$$\frac{(2n)!}{2^{n}n!}$$

You can also look at it as follows. Take the lowest number out of $2n$ numbers, and combine it with one of the $n-1$ other numbers. Then take the lowest remaining number, and combine it with one of the $n-3$ numbers. Continue until all numbers are paired. The number of ways to do this is:

\begin{align*}
(2n-1) \cdot (2n-3) \cdot \ldots \cdot 3 \cdot 1 &= \frac{2n \cdot (2n-1)}{2n} \frac{(2n-2) \cdot (2n-3)}{2(n-1)} \cdots \frac{4 \cdot 3}{2 \cdot 2} \frac{2 \cdot 1}{2 \cdot 1} \\\
 &= \frac{(2n)!}{2^{n}n!}
\end{align*}

Fun fact: the number of pair-wise combinations can be written as a [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial):

$$(2n-1)!! = (2n-1) \cdot (2n-3) \cdot \ldots \cdot 3 \cdot 1$$